# Android JDBC error

Tags: android

I had this code that worked well last Thursday (04/19/2012):

```
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement inst;
    try {
        System.out.println("Connected to the database");
        Class.forName ("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        //217.126.108.151
        conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/prueba;sa;sa1234");
        inst = conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Connected to the database");
        inst.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO TIENDAS (NOMBRE) VALUES ('ZZZZZZZ') ");
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But after the last update of the Android SDK stopped working.

Now I get this error:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: No message resource found for message property prop.servertype**

Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a knee jerk answer here but did you clean your projects and recompile?  I have seen this myself and now routinely clean after an update.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the problem persists. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and rebuild at again. Still if your getting the same problem
try the following way..
-> Instead of localhost in url use this ip : 10.0.2.2

Comment: I found a strange behavior, maybe this helps:
when I clean the project, then jtds-1.2.5.jar file is deleted by Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but since Android >=3.0, network connection have to run in seperate Thread or Task. But if this is the problem, you should get an other exception.
But give it a try :) 
And don't forget to check the permissions in your Manifest.